# In SQL Server 2008 is there a way to generate a report as to how much space on disk each table takes?

Tags: sql-server

IN SQL Server 2008 is there a way to generate a report as to how much space on disk each table takes?

I can do it one by one by checking the storage properties, but I was wondering if there was a way, maybe even a query to generate such a report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) stored procedure to get this information...

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
EXEC sp_spaceused N'Purchasing.Vendor';
GO
```

Result will look like this:

```
name    rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
Vendor  104         48 KB   16 KB   32 KB   0 KB
```

To get the stats for all the tables in the DB use:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="EXEC sp_spaceused '?'"
```

Comment: +1, sp_spaceused is the way to go. I was trying to build a single query solution using the source code from it, when you posted your answer.  You will not be able to easily sort your results though.

Answer (score 4):

in addition to [@kzen's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525945/in-mssql-2008-is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-report-as-to-how-much-space-on-disk-ea/2526034#2526034), to get a single result set **that is sortable** use this:

```
declare @t table (name sysname,rows int,reserved nvarchar(40),data nvarchar(50),index_size nvarchar(50),unused nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @T
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="EXEC sp_spaceused '?'"

--order by reserved space
select * from @t
order by CONVERT(int,LEFT(reserved,CHARINDEX(' ',reserved))) DESC
```

Comment: +1, I imagine that is the preferred resultset anyone would like to see or use in an app or on a web page...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the recommended solution but added a totals query.  The final resulting query is:

```
    Use [DatabaseName]        

    declare @t table 
    (name sysname,rows int,reserved nvarchar(40),data nvarchar(50),index_size nvarchar(50),unused nvarchar(50)) 

    INSERT INTO @T 
        EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="EXEC sp_spaceused '?'"

    --order by reserved space 
     select * from @t Order By [Name] -- order by CONVERT(int,LEFT(reserved,CHARINDEX(' ',reserved))) DESC 

    SELECT 
         Cast(Sum(Cast(Replace(reserved,' KB','') as int)) as varchar(12)) + ' KB' as Total_Reserved,
         Cast(Sum(Cast(Replace(data,' KB','') as int)) as varchar(12)) + ' KB' as Total_Data,
         Cast(Sum(Cast(Replace(index_size,' KB','') as int)) as varchar(12)) + ' KB' as Total_Index_Size,
         Cast(Sum(Cast(Replace(unused,' KB','') as int)) as varchar(12)) + ' KB' as Total_Unused
    FROM @T
```